# Muscles when we restart workout

Tags: muscle-gain

Manage to build muscles after 6-7mounths.Something change your life and your routine so you end ,stop workouts.After one year you start again gym and home workouts.The body will obtain faster muscle growth or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how effective your workouts were and how experienced at lifting you are prior to your break. 6-7 months is not long enough to drastically change your physique. Muscle growth will not suddenly happen when you return, it takes time and a lot of effort to grow muscle and requires you to constantly use it to maintain: "use it or lose it".

**Example 1:**
Person A is a novice and lifts weight for 6 months then take a break for 6 months and then returns. Person A should start back near the beginning (just the barbell, no weight) but will be able to progress back up to where they were over the space of 3-5 months.

**Example 2:**
Person B is experienced, has been working out for 5+ years, gets a [personal best deadlift that puts them in the "Advanced" category](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/DeadliftStandardsKg.html). They take a 6 month break and return. Person B will be able to return and lift weight at a high-novice/intermediate level because their body will not have changed in those 6 months but it may take a long time (years even!) to get their personal best again.